# C++ error when making custom iterator over map values

Tags: c++, hashmap, iterator

I have this code:

```
template <typename Iter>
class map_iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, typename Iter::value_type::second_type> {
public:
    map_iterator() {}
    map_iterator(Iter j) : i(j) {}
    map_iterator& operator++() { ++i; return *this; }
    map_iterator operator++(int) { auto tmp = *this; ++(*this); return tmp; }
    map_iterator& operator--() { --i; return *this; }
    map_iterator operator--(int) { auto tmp = *this; --(*this); return tmp; }
    bool operator==(map_iterator j) const { return i == j.i; }
    bool operator!=(map_iterator j) const { return !(*this == j); }
    reference operator*() { return i->second; }
    pointer operator->() { return &i->second; }
protected:
    Iter i;
};

template <typename Iter>
inline map_iterator<Iter> make_map_iterator(Iter j) { return map_iterator<Iter>(j); }

using route_departure_container = std::map<packed_time, route_departure_o>;

template <typename Iter>
using route_departure_const_iterator = map_iterator;

template <typename Iter>
route_departure_const_iterator<Iter> departure_at(const std::pair<key, const platform_route_o&>& pr, packed_time tm);
```

I am getting compiler errors: syntax error: missing ';' before '*' etc. and C4430 missing type specifier on lines

```
reference operator*() { return i->second; }
pointer operator->() { return &i->second; }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think you need to write `typename std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, typename Iter::value_type::second_type>::reference` (or, to make it less verbose, add a typedef for the base class). Just plain `reference` is not a dependent name, and is not being looked up in the base class. Same with `pointer`. Such are the wonders of two-phase name lookup.

Comment: where should I write it, how?

Comment: Instead of plain `reference` and plain `pointer` when declaring `operator*` and `operator->`

Comment: it does not solve the problem, still the same

Comment: now I got error: 'map_iterator': use of class template requires template argument list on lines ```using route_departure_const_iterator = map_iterator;``` and ```route_departure_const_iterator<Iter> departure_at(const std::pair<key, const platform_route_o&>& pr, packed_time tm);```

Comment: Well, you can't just use `map_iterator` on its own - you need to pass something for its `Iter` parameter. Most likely, you meant `template <typename Iter> using route_departure_const_iterator = map_iterator<Iter>;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227123/discussion-between-rikib161999-and-igor-tandetnik).

Comment: it worked thanks, but now I have another problem,
I have the method like this:
```
template<typename Iter>
route_departure_const_iterator<Iter> departure_at(const std::pair<key, const platform_route_o&>& pr, packed_time tm)
{
return pr.second.second.find(tm);
}
```
and I have error in this code:
```
for (auto route_iterator = departure_at(route, departure_time_);
```
departure_at is underlined red and it says: no instance of function template "departure_at" matches the argument list
but the arguments are of correct types

Comment: I can't read that. If you have another problem, it's probably best to ask a separate question.